# Sending data from mugshot to linux

Tags: debian, users

I'm new to linux. I'm trying to rebuild the `mugshot` app for myself.

It sends data about the user: first name, last name, email, fax, initials and others. The first name and last name are written to `/etc/passwd` as a new user.

And where does mugshot record the rest of the data such as mail and phone number? And is it possible to make them output to `/etc/passwd`? I use Linux Debian.

Comment: what is "the mugshot app"?

Comment: ah, is it [this](https://github.com/bluesabre/mugshot)?

Comment: hey, is this just a random project you chose to reimplement, or does it *really* have to be this functionality? I ask because you're trying to work on something that doesn't only need solid programming and Linux experience, it really needs deep insight into how different parts in a modern Linux desktop environment work with each other! To illustrate: In the following comment, all the **bold** thing are very specific systems that you will have to learn:

Comment: The `mugshot` app is just a python application (see its source code) that talks to via **dbus** to a **dbus service**, namely `org.freedesktop.Accounts.User`, which implements the actual user data managing. There's at least one implementation of that, [accountservice](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/accountsservice/), so you'd want to read the **C** source code of that. While reading it, you'll find that it "simply" calls the `usermod` program for the things you find in /etc/passwd, and for other things, it defer's to **GLib**'s settings mechanism. (which I personally find painful to work with.)

Comment: The other reason I ask is that basically nothing *uses* that info, as saved via glib to configuration files in a very specific format. Like, you can set it, nice, but it doesn't really get read by anything or anyone. So, maybe instead of trying to do the software environment equivalent of learning to swim by jumping into the Barents Sea, I wonder whether some other project to actually learn something useful might be better for you.